# ATmega 328 bootloader + Serial hex upload

Tags: serial-port, arduino-uno, bootloader, atmega

I've got a couple of ATmega 328 PU chips which I want to use barebone.
So I uploaded the "ATmega 328 on a breadboard (8Mhz internal clock)" bootloader via an UNO as ISP to the chip.
It finished sucessfully.
I removed the chip and placed it on another breadboard which I set up with a usb to tll device and a button for the reset to upload the firmware by the serial port of the ATmega 328.

It all worked fine so I tried with the next chip.
Uploading the bootloader worked fine, uploading the firware by serial fails.

```
avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The difference between the chips is that the one that works came witha bootloader from the shop and the other one was bare.
But since I changed the bootloader on both chips to use the internal clock I wouldn't think that that's the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same fuse setting?

Comment: Yep, they are the same. At this point i just think the chip has an issue.

Comment: Try flash some test program for UART communication at 115200 baud by ISP and you will see